# Phone welcome screen - round circle infographic - how it works

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

Has the whole flower art no actual meaning besides amount of usage of the phone? (including the very specific highlighted single dot from on the circle?

I'm puzzled by the [welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPNtl.png). Since the phone is sold with very specific [ubuntu case](http://www.bq.com/gb/accessories-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu.html) I would expect notification OR time displayed there without opening the case.
Quote from the manual:

*This is a picture built from the data collected as you use your phone
– the number of text messages you send, calls you make and so on. The
more you use your phone, the more it changes - and it’s always unique
to you. A double-tap on the centre circle will change the information
displayed.*

The double-tap does nothing on my phone. How do I change/choose the stats or contents shown inside that circle?

Comment: That is strange. Double-tap works as advertised on my Aquaris E4.5 14.10R21. It is not possible to select what you want to see, but the double-tapping changes the provided stats. Including some with rather entertaining value ("You found 200 words in Blabble")

Comment: Update: now after 3 days of use the double tap on infographic start working! As the bubbles/flower art changes with each infographs, the highlighted dots stays in one specific place - like it has some meaning (clock? or....)

Comment: I haven't figured that out yet, though I think "date" seems more likely.  I think it moved one dot this morning, but I had not given it any thought till now.

Comment: It is indeed date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dots are days, the current day is displayed differently. Then the color circles around the infographic represent the activity for the selected category